# Backward mapping from a number to (i, j, k)

Tags: arrays

I have a `3D` array `arr[i][j][k]`. If I want to map `(i,j,k)` to a number then I can do it by using `i*Ry*Rz + j*Ry + k`. What if I want to map it backwards, i.e. given a number, I want `(i,j,k)`. I am not able to derive the formula for that. Can anyone help? 
Range of `i, j, k` are `0` to `Rx, Ry, Rz` respectively.

Either of Row/Column  major order is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work.
Suppose you have number `num` and array `a[Rx][Ry][Rz]`. To get indices `(i, j, k)`, do as follows(this is for column major order):

- `int quotient = num/(Rx*Ry)` and `int remainder = num % (Rx*Ry)`.
- `k = quotient` and `num = remainder`.
- `quotient = num/Rx` and `remainder = num % Rx`.
- `j = quotient` and `i = remainder`.

Finally we get `(i, j, k)`. `a[i][j][k]` will correspond to given `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a 3D array, you'll need to loop in `O(n^3)` to find which values of `i`, `j` and `k` point to a memory location that contains the value you are searching for.

You've actually already proven this with the formula you gave for setting a location.

EDIT: I misunderstood your question.  I thought you wanted to reverse lookup a value stored in memory to find it's location in the array.

Comment: I want to get it without using the loops.

Comment: You can't.  An x-dimensional array must be looped in `O(n^x)` to reverse matchup.